# VSCode git action shortcuts/buttons taking up space in editor tab bar. Why are they there and how can I get rid of them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I hit some shortcut and now I can't figure out how to make this row of shortcuts go away. It's blocking my file tabs, which is the more valuable real estate to me.

[image: the thing I want to go away]

I tried toggling all the options under `View > Appearance`, but didn't find a way to remove these action buttons in the editor tab bar.

Comment: That's just a default part of the gitlens extension. Are you sure you're not just comparing with a file that's not tracked in the git repo? Or did you have the extension disabled before and accidentally enabled it?

Answer (score 0):

That's just a default part of the gitlens extension. I'm not aware of a way to disable it aside from disabling the extension. Or maybe try right clicking them and see if you can uncheck them from the context menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those gitlens-related icons.

1. Run the command `Gitlens: Open Settings` from the Command Palette.
2. That will open a separate custom editor where you can enable or disable gitlens' settins.
3. Scroll way down to the `Menus and Toolbars` section.
4. Disable the `Add to the editor group toolbar` option.
5. That show remove those icons you see in the right of the editor group.

Alternatively, in your `settings.json` find this group of settings:

```
  "gitlens.menus": {
    "editor": {
      "blame": false,
      "clipboard": true,
      "compare": true,
      "history": false,
      "remote": false
    },
    "explorer": {
      "clipboard": true,
      "compare": true,
      "history": true,
      "remote": true
    },
    // etc....many more
    "editorGroup": false,     // add this line anywhere in this setting
```